# Call 2 objects from API on button click ionic2

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I got an API link where i want to get 2 objects from but it's my first time in Ionic2 so I don't know how I can create the function to call them.

I have my homepage with my button

```
<ion-content >

    <button ion-button (click)="getObjects()"><ion-icon name="get"></ion-icon>Get</button>

</ion-content>
```

And in my home.ts file I've tried something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
static get parameters() {
        return [[Http]];
    }
  constructor(public http:Http) {

  }
  getObjects(objectNames)
  var url = 'MYurl';
  var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  return response;

}
```

The objects I want to call are like this:

```
{"lat","long","deviceID","value","id"}
```

Someone who can help to create the right function?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Do you want to have the response of the webservice and put it somewhere ?

Comment: I want to log the objects to the console, http://prntscr.com/dcu9rh this must be logged

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting in `response` variable is an Observable. You will only get the response if you subscribe to it

```
getObjects(objectNames) {
  var url = 'MYurl';
  this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

You can read this if you want more details :
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables